# SocketException: EACCESS (Permission denied)

Tags: java, android, sockets, permissions

I'm trying to create a socket in Android, but I keep on getting EACCESS (Permission denied) errors.

Here is my code in a *separate* thread from the UI thread.

```
public class Client implements Runnable {
    private final static String SERVER_ADDRESS = "173.246.12.125";

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_ADDRESS);
            DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
            ...
```

My android permissions include:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

and just because of some stackoverflow answers, I added this as well:

```
    <permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

but I still cannot create a socket.

What am I missing?
Error output:

```
 java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:623)
        at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.create(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:93)
        at java.net.DatagramSocket.createSocket(DatagramSocket.java:157)
        at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:80)
        at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:65)
        ...

Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
        at libcore.io.Posix.socket(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.socket(BlockGuardOs.java:282)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:608) 
        at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.create(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:93)
        at java.net.DatagramSocket.createSocket(DatagramSocket.java:157)
        at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:80)
        at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:65)
        at com.austinfathman.traffic_server.Client.run(UDP.java:73)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score -3):

I was getting a similar error. It turns out that if you try to bind to a port that is in use, it won't work.

```
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(3996);
```

This worked for me.

Comment: You were getting a different error (`BindException`), from doing a different thing. OP isn't specifying a port at all, and the exception he's getting isn't coming at bind time.